# Problem sending mail via Contact From 7 plugin

Tags: wordpress, sendmail

I have Contact Form 7 plugin installed on my site and I am having trouble sending mail. Readin g some of the documentation on the website, I proceeded to install an additional WP-MAIL-SMTP. But I'm still having trouble sending mail, my output is as follows:

The result was:

```
bool(true)

The full debugging output is shown below:

object(PHPMailer)#98 (53) {
  ["Priority"]=>
  int(3)
  ["CharSet"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["ContentType"]=>
  string(10) "text/plain"
  ["Encoding"]=>
  string(4) "8bit"
  ["ErrorInfo"]=>
  string(35) "Language string failed to load: tls"
  ["From"]=>
  string(16) "xxxxxx@xxxxx.xx"
  ["FromName"]=>
  string(9) "xxxxxx.xx"
  ["Sender"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Subject"]=>
  string(47) "WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xx"
  ["Body"]=>
  string(68) "This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin."
  ["AltBody"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["WordWrap"]=>
  int(0)
  ["Mailer"]=>
  string(4) "smtp"
  ["Sendmail"]=>
  string(18) "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
  ["PluginDir"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ConfirmReadingTo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Hostname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["MessageID"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Host"]=>
  string(20) "xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx"
  ["Port"]=>
  string(3) "465"
  ["Helo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SMTPSecure"]=>
  string(3) "tls"
  ["SMTPAuth"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["Username"]=>
  string(22) "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx"
  ["Password"]=>
  string(13) "xxx"
  ["Timeout"]=>
  int(10)
  ["SMTPDebug"]=>
  int(2)
  ["SMTPKeepAlive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleTo"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["SingleToArray"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["LE"]=>
  string(1) "
"
  ["DKIM_selector"]=>
  string(9) "phpmailer"
  ["DKIM_identity"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_domain"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["DKIM_private"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["action_function"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Version"]=>
  string(3) "5.1"
  ["smtp":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  object(SMTP)#97 (7) {
    ["SMTP_PORT"]=>
    int(25)
    ["CRLF"]=>
    string(2) "
"
    ["do_debug"]=>
    int(2)
    ["do_verp"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["smtp_conn":"SMTP":private]=>
    int(0)
    ["error":"SMTP":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["error"]=>
      string(38) "Called Reset() without being connected"
    }
    ["helo_rply":"SMTP":private]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["to":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(20) "xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxx"
      [1]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
  ["cc":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["bcc":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["ReplyTo":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["all_recipients":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xxx"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["attachment":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["CustomHeader":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["message_type":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  string(5) "plain"
  ["boundary":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(35) "b1_c67f7d9632b63e07cb05722c7e20a46c"
    [2]=>
    string(35) "b2_c67f7d9632b63e07cb05722c7e20a46c"
  }
  ["language":protected]=>
  array(17) {
    ["provide_address"]=>
    string(54) "You must provide at least one recipient email address."
    ["mailer_not_supported"]=>
    string(25) " mailer is not supported."
    ["execute"]=>
    string(19) "Could not execute: "
    ["instantiate"]=>
    string(36) "Could not instantiate mail function."
    ["authenticate"]=>
    string(35) "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate."
    ["from_failed"]=>
    string(35) "The following From address failed: "
    ["recipients_failed"]=>
    string(45) "SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: "
    ["data_not_accepted"]=>
    string(30) "SMTP Error: Data not accepted."
    ["connect_host"]=>
    string(43) "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."
    ["file_access"]=>
    string(23) "Could not access file: "
    ["file_open"]=>
    string(33) "File Error: Could not open file: "
    ["encoding"]=>
    string(18) "Unknown encoding: "
    ["signing"]=>
    string(15) "Signing Error: "
    ["smtp_error"]=>
    string(19) "SMTP server error: "
    ["empty_message"]=>
    string(18) "Message body empty"
    ["invalid_address"]=>
    string(15) "Invalid address"
    ["variable_set"]=>
    string(30) "Cannot set or reset variable: "
  }
  ["error_count":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  int(1)
  ["sign_cert_file":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_file":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sign_key_pass":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["exceptions":"PHPMailer":private]=>
  bool(false)
}

The SMTP debugging output is shown below:

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:

SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 

SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: 

SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 

SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 

SMTP -> NOTICE:
EOF caught while checking if connectedLanguage string failed to load: tls
```

Has anyone any thoughts ?

Regards.

Comment: Well, if your server isn't accepting EHLO or HELO, then your server isn't an SMTP server. I think I'd probably also expect there to be a server name in that error output. How have you configured WP Mail SMTP? What SMTP server are you trying to use? Are you sure it's an SMTP server, and do you have permission to use it? (Also, this isn't really a programming question; this might be more appropriate for the [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) sites...)

Comment: Thanks Matt, firstly I just realised this morning there was a wordpress.stackexchange.com forum. So I'll work on getting the post migrate to there, before I do anything else.

Comment: Could a moderator please assist with moving this post to wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Stephen if you need moderator's attention, you have to flag the post, not to add comment to it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt, thanks for the help.

It was the end of the day when I was setting it up last week and I had the wrong options selected and the wrong password keyed in.

Thanks again.